# Allocating char buffer to hold textual representation for float

Tags: c++, c, c++11

C++11 has the `to_string` function. Under the hood it uses `vsnprintf` to write the value to a char buffer. Then this is used to initialize a string that is returned. Since `vsnprintf` needs the size of the buffer being used, this is calculated and passed in.

For exact types the size is calculated using `sizeof`. For example, for `unsigned long` the calculation is `4 * sizeof(unsigned long)`.

But for a floating point type it is calculated differently. In this case the size of the buffer needed is internally calculated using

```
__gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits<float>::__max_exponent10 + 20
```

I would assume this is just an internal library way of writing

```
std::numeric_limits<float>::max_exponent10 + 20
```

My question is, why is the size is calculated in this way? Why can't they just use the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: The size of a type is not generally related to the range of values it can express. For example a `long double` is typically 12 or 16 bytes long, but that is not a measure of its value range.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate what the longest represent-able value is for integral types, you can use `sizeof` as below example:

In a 32-bit system maximum value for `unsigned long` needs `10` digits, plus negative sign symbol `-` and one byte for `\0`, it at least needs `12` bytes. So, I think below expression is a good estimation:

```
4 * sizeof(unsigned long) // = 16
```

For `float` values it's not true. Here, `max_exponent10` is useful:

> The value of std::numeric_limits::max_exponent10 is the largest
>   positive number n such that 10n is a representable finite value of the
>   floating-point type T.

Comment: Maybe add a couple of float representations since it appears the OP is just expecting "0.123" etc.

Comment: This makes sense but some details are still fuzzy. Like for instance why the `+ 20`?